# Problema al ordenar un arreglo con metodo HeapSort

Tags: c++, visual-studio, winapi

Estoy haciendo un programa en visual studio con c++ y winapi.
En el programa tengo que registrar datos de personas y vacunas para crear carnets/cartillas de vacunación y toda la información se guarda en la lista doblemente ligada llama CARNET.

Una de las funciones que debe tener el programa es que en una ventana organice los nombres de las personas en un listbox ya sea por método QuickSort o HeapSort, para cada método tengo un botón.

En cada botón lo que se hace es limpiar el listbox, luego se calcula el tamaño de la lista, se crea un arreglo donde se copia la información de la lista, se manda a ordenar el arreglo por uno de los dos métodos y finalmente se imprime el arreglo en el listbox.

En el caso del método QuickSort se manda a ordenar el arreglo por el nombre de la persona, en el HeapSort se ordena por el número de identificación de carnet (id).

El método QuickSort ya está listo, el problema es con el método HeapSort, al momento de llamar a este método en vez de que me ordene la información por HeapSort me lo hace por QuickSort, desconozco por qué.
Espero puedan ayudarme, gracias de antemano : )

```
struct CARNET {

    //Datos de vacunas
    wchar_t num_dosis[20]{};
    wchar_t precio[20]{};
    wchar_t tipo[40]{};
    wchar_t marca[40]{};
    wchar_t clave[30]{};
    wchar_t descripcion[150]{};

    //Datos de la persona
    wchar_t estado_civil[40]{};
    wchar_t sexo[40]{};
    wchar_t perfil_riesgo[40]{};
    wchar_t fecha[40]{};
    wchar_t nombre[60]{};
    wchar_t apellidopat[30]{};
    wchar_t apellidomat[30]{};
    wchar_t CURP[25];
    wchar_t RFC[30]{};
    wchar_t calle[60];
    wchar_t colonia[30]{};
    wchar_t ciudad[30];
    wchar_t estado[30];
    wchar_t grupo_ocupa[60];
    wchar_t tel[20]{};
    wchar_t foto[200]{};
    wchar_t documentoID[200]{};

    //Datos de la dosis
    SYSTEMTIME fechaDosis{};
    wchar_t dosis[10]{};
    wchar_t lote[40]{};
    wchar_t centro_vacuna[100]{};
    int id{};

    CARNET* sigui{};
    CARNET* anti{};
};

CARNET* Linicio = NULL; //Indica la cabeza de la lista
CARNET* Lfin = NULL; //Indica el fin de la lista

//Quicksort
void intercambiar(CARNET* a, CARNET* b) {
    
    //Datos de las vacunas
    swap(a->num_dosis, b->num_dosis);
    swap(a->precio, b->precio);
    swap(a->tipo, b->tipo);
    swap(a->marca, b->marca);
    swap(a->clave, b->clave);
    swap(a->descripcion, b->descripcion);
    
    //Datos de la persona
    swap(a->estado_civil, b->estado_civil);
    swap(a->sexo, b->sexo);
    swap(a->perfil_riesgo, b->perfil_riesgo);
    swap(a->fecha, b->fecha);
    swap(a->nombre, b->nombre);
    swap(a->apellidopat, b->apellidopat);
    swap(a->apellidomat, b->apellidomat);
    swap(a->CURP, b->CURP);
    swap(a->RFC, b->RFC);
    swap(a->calle, b->calle);
    swap(a->colonia, b->colonia);
    swap(a->ciudad, b->ciudad);
    swap(a->estado, b->estado);
    swap(a->grupo_ocupa, b->grupo_ocupa);
    swap(a->tel, b->tel);
    swap(a->foto, b->foto);
    swap(a->documentoID, b->documentoID);

    //Datos de la dosis
    swap(a->fechaDosis, b->fechaDosis);
    swap(a->dosis, b->dosis);
    swap(a->lote, b->lote);
    swap(a->centro_vacuna, b->centro_vacuna);
    swap(a->id, b->id);
}

int particionar(CARNET* arr, int inicio, int fin) {
    wstring pivote = arr[fin].nombre;
    int i = inicio - 1;

    for (int j = inicio; j < fin; j++) {
        if (arr[j].nombre<=pivote) {
            i++;
            intercambiar(&arr[i], &arr[j]);
        }
    }

    intercambiar(&arr[i + 1], &arr[fin]);
    return i + 1;
}

void quicksort(CARNET* arr, int inicio, int fin) {
    if (inicio < fin) {
        int indice_pivote = particionar(arr, inicio, fin);
        quicksort(arr, inicio, indice_pivote - 1);
        quicksort(arr, indice_pivote + 1, fin);
    }
}


//HeapSort
void heapify(CARNET* arr, int n, int i)
{
    int largest = i; 
    int l = 2 * i + 1; 
    int r = 2 * i + 2; 

    
    if (l<n && arr[l].id>arr[largest].id)
        largest = l;

    
    if (r<n && arr[r].id > arr[largest].id)
        largest = r;


    if (largest != i) {
        swap(arr[i], arr[largest]);
        
        heapify(arr, n, largest);
    }
}

void heapSort(CARNET* arr, int n)
{
    
    for (int i = n / 2 - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        heapify(arr, n, i);

    
    for (int i = n - 1; i > 0; i--) {
        
        swap(arr[0], arr[i]);
        
        
        heapify(arr, i, 0);
    }
}

BOOL CALLBACK Quicksort_call(HWND ventana1, UINT mensaje, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {
    int seleccion = NULL;
    wchar_t fe[50]{};
    wchar_t idString;
    int id;
    wstring edadString;
    switch (mensaje) {

    case WM_COMMAND: {
        long opc = LOWORD(wParam);
        BARRA_MENU(ventana1, opc);
        switch (LOWORD(wParam)) {
        
        case IDC_BUTTON1: {
            SendDlgItemMessage(ventana1, IDC_LIST2, LB_RESETCONTENT, NULL, 0);

            int tam = 0;
            for (CARNET* auxiliar = Linicio; auxiliar != nullptr; auxiliar = auxiliar->sigui) {
                tam++;
            }

            CARNET* arr = new CARNET[tam];
            int indice = 0;
            for (CARNET* auxiliar = Linicio; auxiliar != nullptr; auxiliar = auxiliar->sigui) {
                arr[indice] = *auxiliar;
                indice++;
            }
            quicksort(arr, 0, tam - 1);
            for (int i = 0; i < tam; i++) {

                wchar_t nombreCompleto[150] = L"";
                wchar_t idStr[20];
                wcscat_s(nombreCompleto, sizeof(nombreCompleto) / sizeof(wchar_t), arr[i].nombre);
                wcscat_s(nombreCompleto, sizeof(nombreCompleto) / sizeof(wchar_t), L" ");
                wcscat_s(nombreCompleto, sizeof(nombreCompleto) / sizeof(wchar_t), arr[i].apellidopat);
                wcscat_s(nombreCompleto, sizeof(nombreCompleto) / sizeof(wchar_t), L" ");
                wcscat_s(nombreCompleto, sizeof(nombreCompleto) / sizeof(wchar_t), arr[i].apellidomat);
                swprintf(idStr, sizeof(idStr) / sizeof(wchar_t), L"%d", arr[i].id);
                wcscat_s(nombreCompleto, sizeof(nombreCompleto) / sizeof(wchar_t), L" ");
                wcscat_s(nombreCompleto, sizeof(nombreCompleto) / sizeof(wchar_t), idStr);



                SendDlgItemMessage(ventana1, IDC_LIST2, LB_ADDSTRING, NULL, (LPARAM)nombreCompleto);
            }
            delete[]arr;
            break;
        }
        case IDC_BUTTON2: {
            SendDlgItemMessage(ventana1, IDC_LIST2, LB_RESETCONTENT, NULL, 0);

            int tam2 = 0;
            for (CARNET* auxiliar = Linicio; auxiliar != nullptr; auxiliar = auxiliar->sigui) {
                tam2++;
            }

            CARNET* arr2 = new CARNET[tam2];
            int indice = 0;
            for (CARNET* auxiliar = Linicio; auxiliar != nullptr; auxiliar = auxiliar->sigui) {
                arr2[indice] = *auxiliar;
                indice++;
            }

            
            
            heapSort(arr2, tam2);
            for (int i = 0; i < tam2; i++) {

                wchar_t nombreCompleto[150] = L"";
                wchar_t idStr[20];
                wcscat_s(nombreCompleto, sizeof(nombreCompleto) / sizeof(wchar_t), arr2[i].nombre);
                wcscat_s(nombreCompleto, sizeof(nombreCompleto) / sizeof(wchar_t), L" ");
                wcscat_s(nombreCompleto, sizeof(nombreCompleto) / sizeof(wchar_t), arr2[i].apellidopat);
                wcscat_s(nombreCompleto, sizeof(nombreCompleto) / sizeof(wchar_t), L" ");
                wcscat_s(nombreCompleto, sizeof(nombreCompleto) / sizeof(wchar_t), arr2[i].apellidomat);
                swprintf(idStr, sizeof(idStr) / sizeof(wchar_t), L"%d", arr2[i].id);
                wcscat_s(nombreCompleto, sizeof(nombreCompleto) / sizeof(wchar_t), L" ");
                wcscat_s(nombreCompleto, sizeof(nombreCompleto) / sizeof(wchar_t), idStr);

                SendDlgItemMessage(ventana1, IDC_LIST2, LB_ADDSTRING, NULL, (LPARAM)nombreCompleto);
            }



            delete[] arr2;
            break;
        }
}

        break;
    }
    case WM_INITDIALOG:
    {
        
        

        break;
    }
    }
    return false;
}
```